# Keep a node in same position despite force layout rest all nodes can be part of force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

How can I keep a particular node in same location ? I mean I run force layout tick moves nodes around  but I want a particular node to stay at same position despite force layout ?

Answer (score 3):

Which version are you using d3 v3 or v4?

In d3 v3, setting fixed = true will ensure that the node is in place. Make sure, that the node has correct x, y values or let the simulation run so that nodes will stabilize before setting fixed = true.

In v4, setting fx and fy properties of the nodes to the coordinate will ensure that the node doesn't move from that coordinate.

Check documentation for more info:
https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_nodes

Answer (score 0):

setting fixed = true  solved the issue.